# Using "print_title_rows = '1:1'" leads to Excel complaining when opening resulting Excel File

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am experiencing a problem whenever I use

```
"ws.print_title_rows = '1:1'"
```

While opening the file Excel complains:

> "Wir haben ein Problem bei einigen Inhalten in 'output.xlsx' erkannt.
>   Sollten wir so viel wie möglich wiederherstellen? Wenn Sie der Quelle dieser Arbeitsmappe vertrauen, klicken Sie auf 'Ja'."
>
> Translated into english: "We have detected a problem with some content in output.xlsx. Should we restore as much as possible? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes."

After clicking 'Yes' Excel creates a file in my temp folder e.g.: "error256600_01.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
<logFileName>error256600_01.xml
</logFileName>
<summary>Fehler in Datei 'Z:\python\skype_ief_export_excel_auswertung\output.xlsx'
</summary>
<removedRecords summary="Folgende Datensätze wurden entfernt:">
<removedRecord>Entfernte Datensätze: Benannter Bereich von /xl/workbook.xml-Part (Arbeitsmappe)
</removedRecord>
</removedRecords>
</recoveryLog>
```

Anyone knows if that is an Excel Problem or a Problem with Python/openpyxl and if so, how to fix it?

My Setup:

```
- Python 3.6.5 (32-bit) on Windows 10 Pro
- Excel 2013 (German)
```

Comment: Can you make some [mcve], showing how you use `"ws.print_title_rows = '1:1'"`, receiving the same error msg?

Answer (score 0):

Sry for not providing an example.
Turns out the reason for the error was that some of my worksheets had a '#' or an '@' in their name. Removing those solved the problem.